Extending type erasure
I am working on a software which makes heavy use of type erasure. This allows duck typing. For now, let us assume that I have something that can fly and that can print. How can I require flying and printing at the same time? I am limited to C++17 and using concepts is not an option.
For example, consider the following implementation for flying:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
class FlyingConcept {
  public:
    virtual ~FlyingConcept() = default;
    virtual void fly() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class FlyingModel : public FlyingConcept {
  public:
    FlyingModel(T t) : t{std::forward<std::decay_t<T>>(t)} {}
    void fly() override {t.fly();}
  private:
    T t;
};

class AnyFlyer {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    AnyFlyer(T t) : flyingConcept{std::make_unique<FlyingModel<std::decay_t<T>>>(std::forward<std::decay_t<T>>(t))} {}
    void fly() {flyingConcept->fly();}
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<FlyingConcept> flyingConcept;
};


When I want to make something fly, I can use the following generic method and invoke it with anything that implements a fly method:
void doFly(AnyFlyer flyer)
{
  flyer.fly();
}

struct OnlyFlying {
  void fly() { std::cout << "can fly" << std::endl;}
};

class BothFlyingAndPrinting {
  public:
    void fly() {std::cout << "can fly (and print)" << std::endl;}
    void print () {std::cout << "can print (and fly)" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
  doFly(OnlyFlying{});            // prints "can fly" 
  doFly(BothFlyingAndPrinting{}); // prints "can fly (and print)"
}


Printing is implemented in a similar fashion:
class PrintableConcept {
  public:
    virtual ~PrintableConcept() = default;
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class PrintableModel : public PrintableConcept {
  public:
    PrintableModel(T t1) : t{std::forward<std::decay_t<T>>(t1)} {};
    void print() override { t.print();};
  private:
    std::decay_t<T> t;
};

class AnyPrintable {
  public:
    template<typename T>
    AnyPrintable(T t) : printableConcept{std::make_unique<PrintableModel<std::decay_t<T>>>(std::forward<std::decay_t<T>>(t))}  {}
    void print() {printableConcept->print();}
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<PrintableConcept> printableConcept;
};

struct OnlyPrinting {
  void print() {std::cout << "can print" << std::endl;}
};

void doPrint(AnyPrintable printable)
{
  printable.print();
}

int main() {
  doPrint(OnlyPrinting{});          // prints "can print"
  doPrint(BothFlyingAndPrinting{}); // prints "can print (and fly)"
}


I need something that can both print and fly at the same time, which only BothFlyingAndPrinting satisfy. I can always reimplement it from scratch, but I do not want to copy/paste that much code. Is there a simple way of "extending" types with type erasure? If I used multiple inheritance (yuck) on both FlyingConcept and PrintingConcept, I would still have to implement that Model.

For just a function call, template and SFINAE might do the job. But, to store a erased type which can fly and print, you have to rewrite some code...

A bit related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/436738/why-is-inheritance-bad-in-a-person-student-model . It their example your question would be "how to require Student and Teacher roles at the same time".

Fyi, what you are doing is not type-erasure, it is only simple polymorphism, look into something like dyno for true type-erasure

@AhmedAEK this is type-erasure. That library certainly looks like less boilerplate but it's doing basically the same thing

AnyPrintable can be constructed from anything with a method print(). OP's code exposes the (normally private) machinery PrintableConcept and PrintableModel, which might be confusing you

@Caleth you are right, the public machinery got me confused, in any case the solution here is to implement yet another concept, though i'd probably create a few macros to make my life easier, and i'd probably use the library for the SBO and faster dispatch and less boilerplate.

You can certainly reduce the amount of boilerplate in your definitions
class AnyBase {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    AnyBase(T&& t) : ptr(new std::decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(t)), &deleter<std::decay_t<T>>) {}
  protected:
    std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)> ptr;
  private:
    template <typename T>
    static void deleter(void* ptr) { delete static_cast<T*>(ptr); }
};

class AnyFlyer : public virtual AnyBase {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    AnyFlyer(T&& t) : AnyBase(std::forward<T>(t)), do_fly(&do_fly_impl<std::decay_t<T>>) {}
    void fly() { do_fly(ptr.get()); }
  private:
    void(*do_fly)(void*);
    template <typename T>
    static void do_fly_impl(void* ptr) { return static_cast<T*>(ptr)->fly(); }
};

class AnyPrintable : public virtual AnyBase {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    AnyPrintable(T&& t) : AnyBase(std::forward<T>(t)), do_print(&do_print_impl<std::decay_t<T>>) {}
    void print() { do_print(ptr.get()); }
  private:
    void(*do_print)(void*);
    template <typename T>
    static void do_print_impl(void* ptr) { return static_cast<T*>(ptr)->print(); }
};

class AnyPrintableFlyer : public virtual AnyPrintable, public virtual AnyFlyer {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    AnyPrintableFlyer(T&& t) : AnyBase(std::forward<T>(t)), AnyPrintable(std::forward<T>(t)), AnyFlyer(std::forward<T>(t)) {}
};

See it on coliru
N.b. it is safe to std::forward the value to multiple virtual base classes, because only AnyBase will move from it.

AnyPrintableFlyer doesn't need virtual inheritance, only those that inherit AnyBase do

@AhmedAEK it does if you want to have AnyCopyableFlyer and AnyCopyablePrintableFlyer etc

Looks very promising. I will try it tomorrow.
